# PHP while in edit mode show selected value in to drop down

Tags: php

This question was asked already, but my question is very simple.

In the my account page, I have the employee country in a dropdown.

How to select a value in the combo, when in edit mode?

Comment: how to do selected equal to selected for combo element in edit mode...

Assume my location usa, when i click the dropdown , by default it has to show the usa,

Comment: I think what you means is, to display a select box with the specified value selected?

Comment: At least, put the snippet of your code here, so other member can see the problems. If you using framework like CodeIgniter, there are helper function `form_dropdown`. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function p_edit_combo($cCurstatus,$h_code_default,$h_name=NULL){

    <select name="<?php echo $cCurstatus;?>" id="<?php echo $cCurstatus;?>" class="main_form_select">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <?php
            $sql_h = "SELECT h_code,h_name FROM med_hl WHERE status = 1";
            $sql_h_result = mysql_query($sql_h);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_h_result)){
                $h_code = $row['h_code'];
                $h_name = $row['h_name'];
        ?>

        <option <?php if($h_code_default==$h_code){ ?> selected="selected" <?php }?> value='<?php echo $h_code; ?>' >
        <?php echo $h_code."|".$h_name; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have the user's country in `$user_country` and the list of all countries in `$all_countries` array:

```
<select id="country">
<?php
foreach ( $all_countries as $country ):
    $selected = "";
    if ( $country == $user_country )
        $selected = "selected";
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country; ?>" 
        selected="<?php echo $selected; ?>">
        <?php echo $country; ?>
</option>
<?php
endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

An `option` tag will be the default for a `select` list when the `selected` attribute is set.  In the following code option 2 will show up as the current selected option when the page loads:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

To achieve this in your PHP code conditionally display the selected attribute on your options against what the current value is:

```
  <option value="1"<?php if($user['country'] == '1') { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>1</option>
  <option value="2"<?php if($user['country'] == '2') { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>2</option>
  <option value="3"<?php if($user['country'] == '3') { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>3</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i have two table

1. " users" colmns(fname,lname,...as on ohther_infomation,hobbies datatype(int))
2. "info" columns (id (primary_key),hobbies(varchar 200)); in which i stored for hobbies name
   In my case i am storing values in from (1,2,3,4) in hobbies (int) filled of users table which i matached them through join after time of fetch them,
   in my info table i stored hobbies by their name (reading, writing,playing,gyming)

- $row has our users selected hobbies (int)
- $rows has list of our hobbies(varchar)

edit.php i need Dropdown value selected :==== And i am Doing Like this :--- (100% Working)**

```
<div class="form-control">

        <label for="hobbies">Hobbies</label>
        <select name="hobbies">
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM info";
            $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

            ?>
                <option <?php if ($rows['id'] == $row['hobbies']) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value='<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>'>
                    <?php echo $rows['hobbies'];  ?>
                </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($err_hobbies)) echo $err_hobbies; ?></span>
    </div>
```