# php: edit selected "select" on button click

Tags: php

I have a select (dropdown) box. On **each** button click, I'd like it to load previously saved position. My code is:

```
<select name="myVariables" style="width:150px">
<?php
foreach ( $variables as $var ) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $var . "\"". $var . " </option>";}
?>
</select>
```

I have a variable $previouslySelected, and every time the button is clicked, this variable can change. I'd like to also change the currently selected option in the select box to the same value. I've tried with:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $var . "\" <?=$previouslySelected==$var ? ' selected=\"selected\"' : '';?\>>". $var . " </option>";}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Also, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171356/php-while-in-edit-mode-show-selected-value-in-to-drop-down#) but it only works the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you submit the form. With GET or POST?

With GET, than you must take the submitted value in this way:

```
$previouslySelected = isset($_GET['myVariables']) ? $_GET['myVariables'] : '';
```

Otherwise with POST:

```
$previouslySelected = isset($_POST['myVariables']) ? $_POST['myVariables'] : '';
```

In PHP 7 you can also do:

```
$previouslySelected = $_POST['myVariables'] ?? '';
```

**EDIT**: Write your echo more readable.

```
$selected = ($previouslySelected === $var) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
echo '<option value="' . $var . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $var . '</option>';
```

Comment: Umm, I am setting previouslySelected and want to change myVariables according to previouslySelected, not the other way around?

Comment: I dont see in your code that you are setting any `$previouslySelected`. If i understood you right, you want to populate your dropdown with the content of `$previouslySelected`. Right?

Comment: @user1418018 Check my EDIT, maybe you had only a typo. An invalid HTML could also cause your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it was the typo! Yes, I didn't post the part of the code where I was setting the `$previouslySelected`, but it was being set. Thanks again!