# How to display a selected option in `drop-down menu` in a PHP update form?

Tags: php, html, postgresql, pgadmin

I have to display a selected option in the drop down list preview, but currently when extracting the value from the database it only shows one option and not the other from the database.

Is there a way to show the actual drop down list option when extracting the known value from the database (PgAdmin)(All code is either HTML,CSS or PHP)

Basically, I want it show the value in the database as the selected option in the Drop-Down menu, as you probably see in the below code I have tried but I am not too sure how to progress further from this point. Also feel free to correct me on errors within my code. I am aware it is a bit to digest but hopefully this will be answered soon :)

```
<?php
   $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=cafe user=postgres password=password");
   if(count($_POST)>0) {
      pg_query($conn,"UPDATE cakesweetorder set id='$_POST[id]', 
         firstname='$_POST[firstname]',
         surname='$_POST[surname]',streetno='$_POST[streetno]', 
         streetname='$_POST[streetname]', 
         state = '$_POST[state]', suburb='$_POST[suburb]', 
         postcode='$_POST[postcode]', email='$_POST[email]', 
         mobno='$_POST[mobno]',colour='$_POST[colour]', 
         toping='$_POST[toping]', 
         chocosentence='$_POST[chocosentence]', 
         quantity='$_POST[quantity]', date='$_POST[date]', 
         file='$_POST[file]',
         tea='$_POST[tea]' 
      WHERE id='$_POST[id]' ");
      $message = "Record Modified Successfully";
   }
   $result = pg_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM cakesweetorder WHERE id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
   $row= pg_fetch_array($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php 
    include_once 'head.php';
?>

<p>
<div class='text-box'>
    <div class='wrapper-glass'>
        <div class='shape-1'></div>
        <div class='shape-2'></div>
        <div class='shape-3'></div>
        <div class='shape-4'></div>
        <div class='shape-5'></div>
        <div class='shape-6'></div>
        <div class='shape-7'></div>
        <div class='shape-8'></div>
        <div class='shape-9'></div>
        <div class='shape-10'></div>
        <div class='container-glass'>  

<title>Cafe Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } 

?>    
</div>
ID: <br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input readonly='readonly' name="id"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<br>

<legend>Name</legend>

Firstname:<div class="bar"><div class="text-bar"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="name" placeholder="Firstname..." value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>"required/></div></div>
Surname:<div class="bar"><div class="text-bar2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="name" placeholder="Surname..."  value="<?php echo $row['surname']; ?>"required/></div></div>


<legend>Address For Delivery</legend>
 Street No: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar3"><input type="number" id="text-bar" class="form-control" name="streetno" placeholder="Street No..."  value="<?php echo $row['streetno']; ?>"required/><br/></div></div>
 Street: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar4"><input type="text" id="text-bar" class="form-control" name="streetname" placeholder="Street Name..."  value="<?php echo $row['streetname']; ?>"required/><br/></div></div>
 State:  
 
 State:  
     <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar5"><select id="state" class="form-control" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['state']; ?>" name="state"></div></div>
 <optgroup label="States">
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
  </select><br></div></div>
 Suburb: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="suburb" placeholder="Suburb..."  value="<?php echo $row['suburb']; ?>" required/><br/></div></div>
 Postcode: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar7"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode..."   value="<?php echo $row['postcode']; ?>" required/><br/></div></div>

<legend>Personal Details</legend>
 Email:<div class="bar"><div class="text-bar8"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email..."  value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" required/><br/></div></div>
 Phone Number: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar9"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobno" placeholder="Phone Number..."   value="<?php echo $row['mobno']; ?>"required/><br/></div></div>

 Colour of Cake: <div class="input-color-container">
 <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar11"><input id="input-color" name="colour" class="input-color" type="color"  value="<?php echo $row['colour']; ?>"></div></div>
</div>
<label class="input-color-label" for="input-color">
</label>
 Topings: <br><br>
 <label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = 'Vanilla') echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt"> Vanilla</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = 'Chocolate') echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >Chocolate</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = 'Caramel') echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >Caramel</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = "Strawberry") echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >Strawberry</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = "M&M's") echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >M&M's</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = "Oreo") echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark"></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >Oreo</span><br/></br></label>
<label class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" name="toping" <?php if(isset($_POST['toping']) && $_POST['toping'] = "Meringue") echo "checked" ?> value="<?php echo $row['toping']; ?>"><span class="checkmark "></span><span class="checkbox-txt" >Meringue</span><br/></label>

 Chocolate Sentences: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar12"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="chocosentence" placeholder="Chocolate sentence..." value="<?php echo $row['chocosentence']; ?>"/><br/></div></div>
 Quantity of Cakes or Sweets: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar13"><input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" value="1" max="10" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity..."  value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" required/><br/></div></div>
 Complimentary Tea: <br>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="radio" name="tea" value="true" <?php if(isset($_POST['tea']) && $_POST['tea'] = 't') echo "checked" ?>value="<?php echo $row['tea']; ?>">
        <label for="tea" class="label1">
            <span>YES</span>
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="tea" <?php if(isset($_POST['tea']) && $_POST['tea'] = 'f') echo "checked" ?>value="<?php echo $row['tea']; ?>">
        <label for="tea" class="label2">    
            <span>NO</span>
        </label>
    </div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<legend>Miscellaneos</legend>
 Date Of Delivery: <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar14"><input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date of Delivery..."  value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" required/><br/><br><br></div></div>
 Custom Order with Instructions: <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" placeholder="Custom Order..." /><br/>
OR Type in Instructions:
<div class="container3">
<div class="bar"><div class="text-bar15"><textarea id="my-text" name="file" rows="5" placeholder="Type Custom Order Here.." value="<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" ></textarea>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div></div></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class='signup-btn' value="Submit" class="button">

</form>
</body>
</html>TAS</option>
      </select><br></div></div>’
```

I have tried something like this but it didn’t really work: (Below), Its a very vague attempt but as I said before it doesn’t work I can’t really figure it out

```
    `<?php
    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=SRIS user=postgres password=password");
    $result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM customer where customer_id = '$_POST[customer_id]'");
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
     
    // isset is set to submit in line 14
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     
    if ($row[pref_gender] == 'M') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = "<option value='M' selected>Male</option>
    <option value='F'>Female</option>";
    }        
     
    if ($row[pref_gender] == 'F') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = "<option value='F' selected>Female</option>
    <option value='M'>Male</option>";
    }        
     
    // retrieves one row of data from the table and displays the fields in the form
    // Book id is a primary key so we can't edit it        
    echo "<p>
     
    <form name='update' action='enter_primarykey.php' method='POST' >
    <li>Customer Id</li><li><input type='text' name='customer_id_updated' value='$row[customer_id]' /></li>
     
    <li>Firstname</li><li><input type='text' name='firstname_updated' value='$row[firstname]' /></li>
    <li>Surname</li><li><input type='text' name='surname updated' value='$row[surname]' /></li> 
     
    <li>Gender</li>
    <li>
    <select name='pref_gender_updated'>
    $statement1                
    </select>
    </li>
     
    <li><input type='submit' name='new' /></li>  </form>
    </p>";
    }
     
    // isset is set to new in line 37
    // uses the primary key to save all the values back into the database when submit is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['new']))
    {
    $result1 = pg_query($db, "UPDATE customer SET firstname = '$_POST[firstname_updated]', 
    surname = '$_POST[surname_updated]', pref_gender = '$_POST[pref_gender_updated]' WHERE customer_id= '$_POST[customer_id_updated]'”);`
```

Below is what I want to change. When displaying the extracted data from the table I want it to show 'QLD' instead it shows the default 'NSW', how do I adapt the code to do this?

```
`State:  
         <div class="bar"><div class="text-bar5"><select id="state" class="form-control" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['state']; ?>" name="state"></div></div>
     <optgroup label="States">
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
      </select><br></div></div>`
```

Comment: Warning: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. You can use [pg_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) to achieve this.

Comment: Is this your problem: "How to show all value from DB with selected option in edit form?" Have you solved it yet? Do you still need any help? If yes, how's your progress so far? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171356/php-while-in-edit-mode-show-selected-value-in-to-drop-down) might help.

Comment: Yep that would be my problem! No I havent solved it, I have tried a couple of things but they don't seem to work. The link does help but I am not to sure what is going on with the answer. Yes, I was going to change some of the code to aid for SQL Injections. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the problem/error do you see? I see that you're mixing html and php variables inside an `echo` statement. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271501/mixing-html-and-php-variables-inside-an-echo-statement/26686237) out it might help. You could use **Escaping double-quoted strings** or **single (or double) quoted strings**. For example: `$myVar = 21;
echo '<div id="' . $myVar . '"></div>';`

Comment: Okay I have tried that but it didn't seem to solve anything but I have edited the original question, my main focus for the question is the bottom 1/3 of the question, That is what I want to change if that helps with the problem/error

Comment: Then it's similar to the checkbox problem, add `if` or `<?=` statement inside each `<option>` tag,  `if($var == value) echo 'selected';`, where `$var` here contains value from DB, and value is the option value.

Comment: okay, thanks will try it. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @qwertyuiop, it's been a while, just checking whether you've solved both problems already?

Comment: Sorry, been a bit busy. I have tried the code for the state and it works as u have done below but i am not sure how to get the extracted value from the database to the `$states = 'VIC'

Comment: Do you save it in same table? if column name is `states` set `$states= row['states']` ?  Do  you mean your problem now is finding the proper `sql` statement?

Comment: yep, that is correct

Comment: I've changed the `$states` variable to `$row['states'] if that's what you mean. But if the problem is finding proper `sql` statement, can you pls update the problem with table details, the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will look somewhat like this:

**PHP**

```
//Do Query (In your case, we can use $row['states']
```

**HTML**

```
`State:  
<div class="bar">
  <div class="text-bar5">
     <select id="state" class="form-control" name="state" name="state"></div></div>
       <optgroup label="States">
       <option value="NSW" <?php if($row['states'] == 'NSW')echo 'selected'; ?> >NSW</option>
       <option value="QLD" <?php if($row['states'] == 'QLD')echo 'selected'; ?> >QLD</option>
<!-- VIC will be selected -->
       <option value="VIC" <?php if($row['states'] == 'VIC')echo 'selected'; ?> >VIC</option>
<!-- VIC will be selected -->
       <option value="SA" <?php if($row['states'] == 'SA')echo 'selected'; ?> >SA</option>
       <option value="NT" <?php if($row['states'] == 'NT')echo 'selected'; ?> >NT</option>
       <option value="TAS" <?php if($row['states'] == 'TAS')echo 'selected'; ?> >TAS</option>
     </select><br>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Your Welcome! I'd still recommend using `PDO` or `pg_prepare` prepared statement to prepare injection. Take a look at this: [pg-prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very simple way.

```html
<?php $row= ("Your SQL QUERY WITH CONNECTION AND EXECUTION"); ?>
    <div>
      <div>
         <select id="select_state" name="state" name="state"></div></div>
           <optgroup label="States">
           <option value="NSW" <?php if($row['states'] == 'NSW')echo 'selected'; ?> >NSW</option>
           <option value="QLD" <?php if($row['states'] == 'QLD')echo 'selected'; ?> >QLD</option>
           <option value="VIC" <?php if($row['states'] == 'VIC')echo 'selected'; ?> >VIC</option>
           <option value="SA" <?php if($row['states'] == 'SA')echo 'selected'; ?> >SA</option>
           <option value="NT" <?php if($row['states'] == 'NT')echo 'selected'; ?> >NT</option>
           <option value="TAS" <?php if($row['states'] == 'TAS')echo 'selected'; ?> >TAS</option>
         </select><br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This also seemed to work!

PHP

```
    $result = pg_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM cakesweetorder WHERE id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
$row= pg_fetch_array($result);


    if ($row['state'] == 'NSW') { 
      echo "</br>"; 
      $statement1 = "<option value='NSW' selected>NSW</option>
          <option value='QLD'>QLD</option>
          <option value='VIC' >VIC</option>
          <option value='SA'>SA</option>
          <option value='NT'>NT</option>
          <option value='TAS'>TAS</option>";
            
    }   
      
    if ($row['state'] == 'QLD') { 
      echo "</br>"; 
      $statement1 = "<option value='QLD' selected>QLD</option>
      <option value='NSW'>NSW</option>
      <option value='VIC' >VIC</option>
      <option value='SA'>SA</option>
      <option value='NT'>NT</option>
      <option value='TAS'>TAS</option>";
  } 


  if ($row['state'] == 'VIC') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = "<option value='VIC' selected>VIC</option>
    <option value='NSW' >NSW</option>
    <option value='QLD'>QLD</option>
    <option value='SA'>SA</option>
    <option value='NT'>NT</option>
    <option value='TAS'>TAS</option>";
  } 
  if ($row['state'] == 'SA') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = "<option value='SA' selected>SA</option>
    <option value='NSW'>NSW</option>
    <option value='QLD'>QLD</option>
    <option value='VIC'>VIC</option>
    
    <option value='NT'>NT</option>
    <option value='TAS'>TAS</option>";
  } 
  if ($row['state'] == 'NT') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = " <option value='NT' selected>NT</option>
    <option value='NSW'>NSW</option>
    <option value='QLD'>QLD</option>
    <option value='VIC'>VIC</option>
    <option value='SA'>SA</option>
    <option value='TAS'>TAS</option>";
  } 
  if ($row['state'] == 'TAS') { 
    echo "</br>"; 
    $statement1 = "<option value='TAS' selected>TAS</option>
    <option value='NSW'>NSW</option>
    <option value='QLD'>QLD</option>
    <option value='VIC'>VIC</option>
    <option value='SA'>SA</option>
    <option value='NT'>NT</option>"
    ;
  }
```

HTML

```
State:  <br>
    <select id='state' class='form-control' name='state'>
    $statement1     
    </select>
  "
```